# mobile pushNotifications without connecting to the Internet?

Tags: android, cordova, c++11, phonegap-build

Can the mobile device receive push notifications without connecting it to the Internet ?

I basically wish to create a local network and allow mobile devices to receive push notifications locally only, without the need to connect to the Internet (like in phonegap/cordova).

Comment: It's not possible, push notifications use GCM, and GCM requires internet

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build your own push mechanism for push to work in local network. one simple way of doing it could be polling the local server at specific interval (periodic pull).

Conventional push mechanism in android such as GCM, requires internet (google servers) to be accessible.